# LINQ won't insert all records in que (possible overwriting of records?)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception

here's my following code (that used to work). It's supposed to add multiple records (I guess objects in LINQ case) to the context object, then submit to the DB.  Issue is, only one record is making it to the DB now, when several used to get inserted.

```
using (DeviceExerciseDataDataContext context = new DeviceExerciseDataDataContext())
{
    foreach(UpdateData tgudData in data.UpdateData)
    {
        tgd.FK = 1;
        tgd.Time = tgudData.TimeStamp;
        tgd.Calories = Convert.ToInt32(tgudData.Calories);
        tgd.HeartRate = tgudData.AvgHr;
        tgd.BenchAngle = tgudData.Angle;
        tgd.WorkoutTarget = 0;
        tgd.Reps = tgudData.Reps;
        context.Datas.InsertOnSubmit(tgd);
    }
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Now, I tried putting the `context.SubmitChanges()` into the foreach block, and this is the error it gave.

> Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table
>   'tablename' when IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   set to OFF.

Mind you, I'm not inserting into the primary key column, and the PK column is set to auto increment, and is identity.

Any ideas for me, as to why my code isn't inserting multiple records anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only use a single class instance for `tgd`, hence only one record is created - you are just overwriting the properties of the existing `tgd` instance repeatedly. Instead you have to new up `tgd` inside the loop, i.e:

```
foreach(UpdateData tgudData in data.UpdateData)
{
    tgd = new WhateverTgdIs();
    tgd.FK = 1;
    tgd.Time = tgudData.TimeStamp;
    tgd.Calories = Convert.ToInt32(tgudData.Calories);
    tgd.HeartRate = tgudData.AvgHr;
    tgd.BenchAngle = tgudData.Angle;
    tgd.WorkoutTarget = 0;
    tgd.Reps = tgudData.Reps;
    context.Datas.InsertOnSubmit(tgd);
}
```

Comment: @BrokenGlass thanks!  But now I'm getting an error of "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use."  Any ideas?  Not even one record got inserted.

Comment: @abatishchev, I've set the PK to AutoGenerate = True, and Auto-Sync = OnInsert, but I'm still getting the "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.", do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Fritos is it possible that there is a Unique Constraint on FK field?

Comment: @msarchet, Primary Key on the FK field is set to false, and Nullable is set to true.

Comment: @Fritos there is still the ability to set up a unique constrain outside of that.

Comment: @msarchet, Where shall I look?

Comment: @msarchet, I've created a new thread since this is a new issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469316/duplicatekeyexception-in-linq-but-ive-set-auto-increment-and-auto-sync